# Accessibility Ionic 4 routing focus is at the bottom of the page

Tags: javascript, angular, accessibility, ionic4

i have this really annoying problem in my `Ionic 4` application that when I change page the screen reader focus is at the bottom of the page which means that my users will have to reverse through the content to get to my `main` content section.

i did some research and this seems to be a problem with `Angular` [Angular accessibility documentation](https://angular.io/guide/accessibility)

Here they suggest that you should set focus on the `main` content.

However when I attempt this using:

```
  ionViewDidEnter() {
    const mainHeader = document.querySelector('#mainContent');
    if (mainHeader) {
      (mainHeader as HTMLElement)?.focus();
    }
  }
```

it doesn't really do anything.

Has anyone had a similar issue and know how I might fix it?

**Edit**

I have also tried with the `viewChild`:

```
  @ViewChild('mainPage') mainContent: ElementRef;    
  ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events.pipe(filter(e => e instanceof NavigationEnd)).subscribe(() => {
      this.mainContent.nativeElement.focus();
    });
  }
```

And setting the `mainPage` element's `tabIndex=0`:

```
<div #mainPage tabindex="0"><ion-router-outlet main></ion-router-outlet></div>
```

Yet still no focus.

Comment: Is there something it dev console?

Comment: @DawidWekwejt no sadly not

Comment: Could it be a timing issue? Is the focus being set too early and then whatever causes the focus to end up at the bottom of the page moves the focus again. Should be easy to test just add a 2 second delay to the focus change and see if it works. If this is the case then you just need to find the right place to hook into so it changes the focus after whatever Angular is doing to break it.

Comment: Has there been any progress on this? A fix from Ionic side?